# Cycling through text on Click - using Event Listeners

Tags: javascript, event-handling, addeventlistener, event-listener

I'm attempting to create a tic tac toe game using javascript, where if a user clicks on a cell the cell displays an X, then another click would result in O, and a third click would result in a blank cell, and these could be cycled through out.

Im struggling to make it work using the event listeners however, as once the values recorded I can't seem to cycle back through. Any Suggestions?

```
var cell = document.querySelector('#one');

var options=["X","O"," "]

cell.addEventListener("click",function(){
  cell.textContent = options[0];

cell.addEventListener("click",function(){
  cell.textContent = options[1];

cell.addEventListener("click",function(){
  cell.textContent = options[2];
})
})
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the  Remainder `%` operator to loop the array with something like this:

```
var cell = document.querySelector('#one');

 var options=["X","O"," "]
 var i = 0
 cell.addEventListener("click",function(){
 cell.textContent = options[i%options.length];
 i++;
 })
```

Answer (score 1):

Add only one eventListener to your cell with one corresponding function.
An easy approach would be a counter declared globally: let c = 0;
In the function you could increase the counter (c++) and then use it to access your options-array index via the modulo-operator...